# Mostrar alert con un Gauge chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-chart-api

estimados tengo actualmente un gauge chart en mi pagina la cual funciona, mi consulta es como puedo hacer para que al pinchar un medidor se levante un alert?.

estoy trabajando con este codigo

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el **Gauge chart** no esta permitido agregarle un evento click; por lo general el evento click para los gráficos de google se harían así:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler(e) {
  alert('Click');
}
```

Pero el gráfico que usas no lo contempla, es decir google dice

> No triggered events

Para más info puedes verlo [aquí](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge#events).

Una solución que puedes utilizar es crear un div vacío relativamente posicionado en la parte superior del medidor y registrar el evento de clic en ese:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
      }
```

```css
body {
  position:relative;
}

#chart_div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 400px; 
}

#chart_div_clickable {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:120px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:120px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="chart_div_clickable" onclick="alert('Hola');"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias es lo que necesitaba !

Comment: A su orden, si te sirvió por favor me podrías tildar mi respuesta como valida? gracias